# На С# разработать библиотеку, которая реализует простую ORM

Tags: c#, orm

Появилась необходимость написать на C# библиотеку, в которой будет реализована простая ORM. С# изучаю не так давно, по этому не знаю с чего начать. Может кто-то делал такое или есть пример выполнения.

Вот полное задание
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: _Простую_ ОРМ? А простую операционную систему не нужно? Или там простенькую программу для распознавания рукописного ввода?

Comment: Мы вам верим, что у вас появилась такая необходимость.

Comment: @VladD   понимаю как это звучит, но мне прислали такое тестовое задание

Comment: @Lt_23: Это тестовое задание на должность сениора? Если на джуниора, позвольте посоветовать вам послать их матом.

Comment: @VladD  в том то и дело, что junior. хотелось бы хоть что-то сделать и показать.

Comment: @Lt_23: Это не джуниоровское задание. Вас, эээ, дурят. Если вы сделаете это задание, вы смело можете претендовать на сениорскую должность и зарплату. Они, понятно, хотят получить прекрасного программиста за мизерные деньги. Если общение с компанией начинается с жульничества с их стороны, ничего хорошего из этого не выйдет. Постарайтесь соскочить, не теряя лица.

Comment: @VladD  А что тут уровня сениора? Конечно не джуниор, но сениора тут не вижу.

Comment: @vitidev: Ну, я как сениор не вижу сходу, как можно простенько заимплементировать мэппинг к произвольной базе данных. Тут нужна вот сразу навскидку как минимум архитектура коннекторов и серьёзное понимаете того, что и как в нём должно происходить. Если это миддловское задание, я к вам работать не пойду, меня в джуны запишут.

Comment: А вроде ИЗИ: написать менеджера с методами типа persist, remove, flush, написать интерфейс драйвера базы CRUD, реализовать драйвер к базе на основе интерфейса, класс содержащий данные о сущности ([[type, val, column]], primary key, название таблицы). Коннектор можно передавать в manager, на основе его определять драйвер. Когда сущность передаем в менеджер в persist, разбираем библиотечные атрибуты типа названия таблицы, ключа (или на основе файла кого-нить маппить), данные класса полученных через рефлексию и сохраняем в хранилище менеджера, при flush передаем этот класс в нужный метод драйвера

Comment: @Firepro  Там почти все просто, но вы забыли про C(R)UD - чтение нужно, а это, скорее всего, кастомный IQueryable, что уже никак не жуниор. Хотя....можно просто сделать маппер и на этом все - будет как в Dapper

Comment: Подтверждаю. Тут проблема даже не в уровне джуниора - сеньора. А в том что на эту задачу надо убить дофига времени. Я лично не вижу как её грамотно написать менее чем за 3 дня (не из палок и г...). Да еще и покрыть тестами грамотно - отдельный квест. Надо учитывать что поскольку это тестовое задание, то писать надо так чтобы можно было детально обосновать почему что и как и почему не вот так. Вас не в гугл берут случайно (сарказм)? Обычно вроде тестовое задание при приеме на работу занимает максимум день?

Comment: @Firepro а есть ссылка на пример выполнения этого, ничего в инете не могу найти

Comment: @Lt_23 Врятли есть готовые материалы с описанием полного процесса создания ORM, ищите уже готовые ORM смотрите их код, архитектуру, можно посмотреть как это выглядит на других языках и т.д. Хотя вот тут, что-то есть для .net: https://www.codefluff.com/using-reflection-to-write-your-own-orm/